# PrimeFaces split button open hover

Tags: primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 5.1, In split button click open menuitem but I need same split button need to hover Is this possible or only menuBar component to show this option?

```
<p:splitButton value="Save" actionListener="#{buttonView.save}" update="messages" icon="ui-icon-disk">
<p:menuitem value="Update" actionListener="#{buttonView.update}" update="messages" icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w" />
<p:menuitem value="Delete" actionListener="#{buttonView.delete}" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-close" />
<p:separator />
<p:menuitem value="Homepage" url="main.xhl" icon="ui-icon-extlink" />
</p:splitButton>
```

Comment: Sure, look at the javascript source of the component and add a hover eventhandler just like the click handler

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You can make it like this with help of jQuery:

```
<p:splitButton value="Action" action="#{bean.doMainAction}" widgetVar="itemBtn_#{item.id}" menuStyleClass="hoverOverlay">
    <p:menuitem value="Sub action 1" action="#{bean.doSubAction1}" />
</p:splitButton>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        PF('itemBtn_#{item.id}').getJQ().on("mouseenter", function() {
            PF('itemBtn_#{item.id}').menu.show();
        });
        PF('itemBtn_#{item.id}').getJQ().on("mouseleave", function() {
            PF('itemBtn_#{item.id}').menu.hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I had the code above in p:dataGrid (or p:dataTable, ui:repeat... etc.) therefore I use there also **item.id**. You don't need it there otherwise.
There are also show and hide actions provided by PrimeFaces:

```
PF('itemBtn_#{item.id}').show();
PF('itemBtn_#{item.id}').hide();
```

But don't use them as they use effects and showing/hiding overlay isn't working good with them because effect take some time to finish.

Following code is for hovering overlay menu (to keep it open even after leaving split button itself). It is bound globally to all overlay menus with class **hoverOverlay**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("body").on("mouseenter", ".hoverOverlay", function() {
            $(this).show();
        });
        $("body").on("mouseleave", ".hoverOverlay", function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can bind it to one button instead without using custom **hoverOverlay** class like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        PF('itemBtn_#{item.id}').menu.on("mouseenter", ".hoverOverlay", function() {
            PF('itemBtn_#{item.id}').menu.show();
        });
        PF('itemBtn_#{item.id}').menu.on("mouseleave", ".hoverOverlay", function() {
            PF('itemBtn_#{item.id}').menu.hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```